# webrequest get error page but browser get correct page

Tags: c#, html, download

I am writing an application that needs to download a webpage. however i use this code scheme to get html :

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(address);                
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();                

System.IO.Stream data = response.GetResponseStream();
System.IO.StreamReader reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(data, true);
string htmlCode = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

i have a problem with urls from this site : `http://www.jamejamonline.ir/`

When i try to get a page in this way, redirected to error page,
but all webbrowsers show correct html page.

how can i get around this problem?

Comment: What does the error page say? Does the site require cookies?

Comment: You can probably do this with less code using the WebClient.DownloadString() method

Comment: the error page is : "There is an error in site. please try again later"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

specify an user agent like this

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(address);  
request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:2.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0.1";                
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();                

System.IO.Stream data = response.GetResponseStream();
System.IO.StreamReader reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(data, true);
string htmlCode = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

I tried it and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

The request method seems to be missing in the piece of code that you showed. Add this line after the line where you create the request:

```
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Get
```

Comment: Default value of request.Method is "Get"

Comment: the error page is : "There is an error in site. please try again later"